# Regular expression: Match string between two slashes if the string itself contains escaped slashes

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to build a regular expression that matches regular expressions between two forward slashes. My main problem is that regular expressions themselves can contain forward slashes, escaped by a backslash. I try to filter them out with a negative lookbehind assertion (only match the closing slash if there is no backlash at the current position), however, now I'm having the problem that I don't get the match, if the regex itself actually ends with a escaped backslash.

test program:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
teststrings=[
     """/hello world/""", 
     """/string with foreslash here \/ and here\//""",
     """/this one ends with backlash\\\\/"""]

patt="""^\/(?P<pattern>.*)(?<!\\\\)\/$"""

for t in teststrings:
    m=re.match(patt,t)
    if m!=None:
        print t,' => MATCH'
    else:
        print t," => NO MATCH"
```

output:

```
/hello world/  => MATCH
/string with foreslash here \/ and here\//  => MATCH
/this one ends with backlash\\/  => NO MATCH
```

How would I modify the assertion to only hit if there is a single backlash at the current position, but not two?

Or is there a better way to extract the regex? (Note, in the actual file I try to parse the lines contain more than just the regex. I can't simply search for the first and last slash per line and get everything inbetween.)

Comment: In your real-world example, could you have escaped slashes before/after the first/last "real" slash?

Comment: yes, the string after the regex can have arbitrary characters, including slashes

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this:

```
pattern = re.compile(r"^/(?:\\.|[^/\\])*/")
```

**Explanation:**

```
^       # Start of string
/       # Match /
(?:     # Match either...
 \\.    # an escaped character
|       # or
 [^/\\] # any character except slash/backslash
)*      # any number of times.
/       # Match /
```

For your "real-world" application (finding the first "slash-delimited string", disregarding escaped slashes), I'd use

```
pattern = re.compile(r"^(?:\\.|[^/\\])*/((?:\\.|[^/\\])*)/")
```

This gets you the following:

```
>>> pattern.match("foo /bar/ baz").group(1)
'bar'
>>> pattern.match("foo /bar\/bam/ baz").group(1)
'bar\\/bam'
>>> pattern.match("foo /bar/bam/ baz").group(1)
'bar'
>>> pattern.match("foo\/oof /bar\/bam/ baz").group(1)
'bar\\/bam'
```

Comment: I think you need `\\.` to match an escaped character.